# React native 422 Unprocessable Entity error returned from server when using POST Fetch call with content type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch

I'm calling a simple login **API** with **POST** request following are the params:
**Headers**:
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
**Body**:
email: String
password
**Error returned from server is**:422 Unprocessable Entity

**CODE:**

```
  var formBody = new FormData();
formBody.set("email", "test5@gmail.com");
formBody.set("password", "12345678");


const data = new URLSearchParams(new FormData(details));
return  dispatch => {
    dispatch(requestData());
    try {
        fetch(`${BASE_URL}users/sign_in`, {
            method: 'POST',
            // headers: Interceptor.getHeaders(),
            headers: {
                Accept:'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
              },
            //   body: formBody
             body: data

        })
            .then(res => res.json())
                .then(result=>
                {
                    if (result.success === false) {}
                }
                )


    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error',error)
        dispatch(failureData(error))
    }
}
```

[Screenshot of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnsYn.png)

Comment: you should add the code from the image to the question...

Comment: @MosheSlavin done, have a look

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer, 422 is basically caused by semantic issue, in my case, Origin of my Request Header was going null.

Comment: what is that mean origin of request header ?